# Loading screen while doing heavy task

Tags: java, screen, loading

When performing a task, that takes a few seconds and makes the whole program lag, is there a way to implement a screen that waits for the task to complete and then remove itself?

Comment: Thanks in advantage? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your task is runned when the user start the application you can use the [Splash screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html). Otherwise I suggest you to run the task in another thread and [get the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352638/getting-the-output-of-a-thread) when the thread has finished to perform the task