# Java Timer Thread Operation

Tags: java

I am using Timer Thread to run a simple print function. The thing is that if I set my delay time is 1000ms, the program would just exit without any output.

But if I switch to 100ms, the program would be just fine.

```java
public class TimerTaskTest01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 1000);
    }
}
class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hello World... ");
        }
        System.out.println("END");
    }
}
```

I think maybe the main thread is running too fast. But is there anyone can tell me that if I am right or not...

Comment: How are you executing the program and which JDK are you using? I cannot reproduce the problem even with a 10 second delay running from Eclipse IDE and JDK 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your application is probably still running (or should be), regardless of the scheduled timeout. According to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), creating a `Timer` using the default constructor will create a *user thread*, so it's "capable of keeping an application from terminating".

If you run the application with a debugger, you should see the timer thread being kept alive in the background as something like

```
Thread[Timer-0](Running)
```

Changing the `Timer` to use a *daemon thread* instead with

```
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
```

will show that the thread actually terminates immediately with the rest of the program when `main()` finishes:

```
terminated, exit value 0
```

Trying your code with [ideone](https://ideone.com/KgsSUP) also verifies that the program doesn't terminate after `main()`, but instead continues execution until the JVM is terminated (there's a built-in five-second timeout), after which the expected output is printed.

Whether or not the output is printed at the scheduled time or when the application exits, is probably dependent on the underlying OS and JVM.

Comment: I agree with this.  When used in a normal app (main(...)).  However, the results are different when used in a simple jUnit test case, where it in fact exits and behaves like a daemon regardless of options.  This seems like a jUnit issue though.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Waiting for a Timer to finish in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321620/waiting-for-a-timer-to-finish-in-java).  Essentially, your main thread is completing before the Timer schedule occurs.

Comment: The default constructor of `Timer` starts a _user thread_ (not a daemon), which should be "capable of keeping an application from terminating", according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

The schedule method will call your task with specified delay. 1000 ms or 100 ms for your case.

From your code, the main thread will run that scheduler, then exit. Your assumption that 100 ms delay will be fine is not always true. There is possibility that your system will run the main thread faster than 100 ms and do not have time to run your task.
This is what everybody called 'Race Condition'.

Answer (score 0):

You start your task and then your program ends.  You need to wait for the timer/tasks to complete before exiting your program:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    int sleepTimeMS = 1000;
    timer.schedule(new MyTask(), sleepTimeMS);
    Thread.sleep(sleepTimeMS + 50); // just in case, an extra 50ms
}
```

The above solution is moderately terrible.  A better way to do it would be to you some scheduler that allowed you to wait until all its tasks are complete.  @fedup's link suggests `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Another alternative would be to externally track task starts & stops with something like an `Atomic<int>`.  This could be error prone and lead to early program exits, or sleeping forever.

I'd go with the scheduler.