# Why notifyAll() doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

After been thinking about a solution, i don't know why this code doesn't works properly.

If I execute `mediaPlayer.start()`, the thread enters on loop and `wait()`, but then, when `mediaPlayer` calls `OnCompletionListener`, `notifyAll()` doesn't wake from `wait()`, and loops in `wait()` state forever...

(Supposing that 'Music Thread' is properly started at the start of the class, and the same with `MediaPlayer` object)

```
private synchronized void set()
{
    while(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
    try {     
        wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    //DO SOMETHING (THE PROBLEM IS THAT NEVER REACHES THIS CODE)
}




private synchronized void reproductor()
{
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            notifyAll();   //because mediaPlayer.isPlaying() changes

        }
    });
}



private class Music implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            reproductor();
            while(true) {
                set();
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if i use contrary statement in loop it works properly (`!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()`), why?

Comment: Looks like a classic "lost notification" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999100/is-there-a-block-until-condition-becomes-true-function-in-java/26218153#26218153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't notifying the same object you're waiting on. You're notifying the listener object, which is an instance of an anonymous class implementing the listener interface. You need to qualify `notifyAll()` as `XXX.this.notifyAll()`, where `XXX` is the same of the class enclosing the `set()` and `reproductor()` methods.