# wait() notify() is not working as expected

Tags: java, android, multithreading, wait, notify

I have a `MyService` class which contains a **nested** `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class MyService {
   private Object lock;
   public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         synchronized(lock) {
           doTask();
           lock.wait();
           Log.d(TAG, "After wait ...");
         }
      }
   } 
   private synchronized void doTask() {
      Log.d(TAG, "do task ...");
      synchronized(lock) {
          lock.notify();
      }
   }
}
```

As you see above, when `onReceive()` is called, my code run `doTask()` in a `synchronized` block. Then, in `doTask()` function, my code run `lock.notify()`. I expected to see the log in terminal `Log.d(TAG, "After wait ...");`

I run my Android project. When onReceive() is triggered, I can see the log "**do task ...**", then, it is hanging there, I can't see log "**After wait ...**", why my wait-notify is not working as expected?

Comment: The same thread is calling both methods?

Comment: Possibly a "lost notification".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999100/is-there-a-block-until-condition-becomes-true-function-in-java/26218153#26218153  `lock.notify()` _does not do anything at all_ unless some other thread is already waiting in a `lock.wait()` call.

Answer (score 0):

> I run my Android project. When onReceive() is triggered, I can see the
>   log "do task ...", then, it is hanging there, I can't see log "After
>   wait ...", why my wait-notify is not working as expected?

`BroadcastReceiver`s run always on the ui thread. if `MyService` runs on the Ui thread, what you are experiencing is a deadlock. It could be also that `MyService` runs on a background thread. If the notify is executed before wait, then the thread running MyService is waiting for the next notify