# Do code while element invisible

Tags: java, selenium

Have some trouble with making the test in Selenium. I have, like simple test (where you have to select answers and proceed). For assuring that test is finished I want to check that the `//span[contains(text(),'%Finishing exam popup text%')]` is not visible. And while it is not visible - do some other stuff to proceeding in the test. Can somebody help me or give some better advice how to do such test?

Comment: try `//span[contains(text(),'Finishing exam popup text')]`

Comment: in percents that was the "some text that I use", not the actual text =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'%Finishing exam popup text%')]")));
```

Comment: Then test will wait until the pop-up appears. And I want to do the test that will do something until pop-up will appear. For example - press on some button and do this until the pop-up with text "lorem ipsum" will appear.

Comment: I don't know what that "other stuff" is, but maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/5999146/6156035

Comment: Not helped. I wrote an example of "other stuff" in the previous comment.