# How to print half number by thread1 and second half by thread2

Tags: java, multithreading

I have made a programe which print 5 number using 2 threads.

```
public class Class1 {

static int value = 6;
 public void show() {
    for (int i = 0; i < value; value--) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Number: " + value);
    }
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Class1 main = new Class1();

    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            main.show();
        }
    };

    new Thread(runner, "Thread 1").start();
    new Thread(runner, "Thread 2").start();
}   }
```

It gave me output like this:

```
Thread 1 - Number: 6
Thread 2 - Number: 6
Thread 1 - Number: 5
Thread 2 - Number: 4
Thread 1 - Number: 3
Thread 1 - Number: 1
Thread 2 - Number: 2
```

But i want that it gave me output like this

```
Thread 1 - Number: 6
Thread 1 - Number: 5
Thread 1 - Number: 4
Thread 2 - Number: 3
Thread 2 - Number: 2
Thread 2 - Number: 1
```

I know it is easy we can simply use **if else condition in the show()** Method but **i don't want to use if else** in the show() method, i want to **change some thing in the main() method** which do the work done.

Comment: Do you want your second thread to begin only when the first one ends ?

Comment: @Hearner i want the out which i show at the last of my post

Comment: @Hearner i want when Thread 1 print 6,5,4 then we lock Thread 1 and then thread 2 print 321

Comment: The simplest solution is to use one thread! Anything else is going to look very cumbersome and inefficient.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i know use one thread will solve the problem but its my Uni assignment, i search on internet but unable to do that work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a 'block until condition becomes true' function in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999100/is-there-a-block-until-condition-becomes-true-function-in-java)

Comment: @PeterLawrey it can be easily done by using if statement in the show() method but they said you can not use if else do all your work in the main method

Comment: @Mike no buddy my question is different one

Comment: The simplest solution is to not call `start()` but call `run()` instead.  The problem is the assignment is daft so you end up having to assume requirements which don't make sense.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the queston is simple the Thread 1 should print 6,5,4, then Thread 2 sould print next three integer. What's confusing in that ?

Comment: @shauntait because the simplest solution is to a) not use threads, b) not use a variable, c) not use any kind of co-ordination except via the main thread. Once you start adding code which doesn't do anything useful there is no limit to amount of pointless code you could write. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can wait to start the second thread after first thread  has finished, basically you need to synchronize thread execution.

To do that you can:

- enter in a `synchronized` block holding the same key
- using the `wait` `notify` keywords on the same lock
- using the java `Lock` class
- using `join` on first thread to wait that he finishes before starting the second
- use an `Observable` to coordinate start of threads

And many others.

Comment: Can you make an edit in my code, so i can understand better. i am new to Threads it will be a great favour

Answer (score 1):

Firt thing first. You are not using **synchronization in your Threads** and if you want to use `join()` you need to use an `if` in your run method and

```
static int value = 6;
```

Is not thread safe! For better use an **AtomicInteger** and for control of theads check 
[ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below:

```
final int number = 6;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i< number/2;i++){
                System.out.println("Thread 1 Number: "+i);
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = number/2; i< number;i++){
                System.out.println("Thread 2 Number: "+i);
            }
        }
    });
        t1.run();
        t2.run();
```

Comment: OK. I have edited for thread2 run after thread 1. I hope this helps.

Comment: Note: if you replace `start()` with `run()` you don't need join. ;)

Comment: I think the OP needs to make it look like there is multiple threads involved.

Comment: yeah @mstfyldz if there are for example 10 threads then we override run() Method 10 times?

Comment: @mstfyldz i think thats not good approach, what is your opinion abput it?

Comment: So you should give more detail for your requirements for example how to divide number between threads? @shauntait

Comment: @mstfyldz your solution is perfectly fine, but if we have for example 4 threads then we override the run() method 4 time?? (or there is any other way? i actually dont want to override run() agian and agian) like in the above case we have 2 threads so you override run() method 2 times

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrintHalfNumber {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Printer sp = new Printer();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    executor.submit(new SecondHalfProducer(sp, 10));
    executor.submit(new FirstHalfProducer(sp , 10));
    executor.shutdown();
  }

}


class Printer {

  Semaphore secondHalf = new Semaphore(0);
  Semaphore firstHalf = new Semaphore(1);

  public void printSecondHalf(int num) {
    try {
        secondHalf.acquire();
    }catch(InterruptedException exception) {

    }
    for(int i = (num/2) + 1 ; i <= num ; i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Thread 2 - Number: " + i);
    }

    firstHalf.release();
  }

  public void printFirstHalf(int num) {
    try {
        firstHalf.acquire();
    }catch(InterruptedException exception) {

    }
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= num/2 ; i++) {
        System.out.println("Thread 1 - Number: " + i);
    }

        secondHalf.release();
  }

}

class SecondHalfProducer implements Runnable {

  Printer sp;
  int index;

  SecondHalfProducer(Printer sp , int index) {
    this.sp = sp;
    this.index = index;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    sp.printSecondHalf(index);
  }
}

class FirstHalfProducer implements Runnable{
  Printer sp;
  int index;

  FirstHalfProducer(Printer sp , int index) {
    this.sp = sp;
    this.index = index;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
        sp.printFirstHalf(index);
  }
}
```

***Output of the program is :***

```
Thread 1 - Number: 1

Thread 1 - Number: 2

Thread 1 - Number: 3

Thread 1 - Number: 4

Thread 1 - Number: 5

Thread 2 - Number: 6

Thread 2 - Number: 7

Thread 2 - Number: 8

Thread 2 - Number: 9

Thread 2 - Number: 10
```