# android - calling API service inside for loop

Tags: java, android

```
for(TrackOrderModel trackOrderModel : ordersList)
{
    order_id = trackOrderModel.getOrder_id()
    //this is the method which calls API service
    getDetails(order_id);
}
```

A simple for loop to get order details of given order id. But I'm facing the issue that API is not calling in the loop it's calling after the completion of the loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5999146/8428193

Comment: What do you mean by not calling in loop and calling outside it? Can you share your `getDetails(int id)` method too?

Comment: maybe API takes time to call while loop will keep running.it can produce dilemma to look like its running after the loop.