# Playing audiofiles one by one?

Tags: java, android

I'm newbie in java. So the program should take the user entered text and if there is "a" it gonna play a-sound, if there is "b" it gonna play b-sound.And it must play this sounds one by one even if there are multiple "a" or "b". Here is my code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    final EditText etStart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStart);
    final EditText etFinish = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFinish);
    final char[] arr = etStart.getText().toString().toCharArray();
    final MediaPlayer as = MediaPlayer.create(R2d2Activity.this, R.raw.as);
    final MediaPlayer bs = MediaPlayer.create(R2d2Activity.this, R.raw.bs);
    final SoundPool sp;
    final int a;
    final int b;
    final int t;
    sp = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    a = sp.load(this, R.raw.as, 1);
    b = sp.load(this, R.raw.bs, 1);
    final String value = etStart.getText().toString();
    final Thread timer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(1300);
        // Do some stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        }
        });
    bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int n = 0;
            String value;
            String first;
            value = etStart.getText().toString();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           //actual code
            for (int i=0; i<value.length(); i++){
                first = etStart.getText().toString().substring(i, i+1);
                if(first.contentEquals("a")){
                    as.start();
                    as.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                            //when finished


                             }
                    });

                        }else{
                            }
                if(first.contentEquals("b")){
                    bs.start();

                        }else{
                            }

            }



        }
    });
```

The problem is that it starts playing audio files all at one time. I tried to add some OnCompletionListener, but I don't know what to do with it. Help me please.

Comment: Use a line listener and you'll get events on start and stop. Then you have to make the method wait (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289434/how-to-make-a-java-thread-wait-for-another-threads-output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is

```
//define a variable to be used as index.
int audioindex = 0;
//Extract the files id into an array
int[] audioFileIds=new int[]{R.raw.as,R.raw.bs};
```

Then in your `MediaPlayer` `onCompletionListener` put something like following.

then in your OnCompletionListener.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
    // @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
    // File has ended, play the next one.
   FunctionPlayFile(audioFileIds[audioindex]);
   audioindex+=1; //increment the index to get the next audiofile
     }
});
```