# wait and notify concept in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Assume the following method is properly synchronized and called from a thread A on an object B:

wait(2000);

After calling this method, when will the thread A become a candidate to get another turn at the CPU?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  Have you read the JavaDoc, or done any research?

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289434/how-to-make-a-java-thread-wait-for-another-threads-output

Comment: @Hardik - I am here to clarify my doubt. If you do not have interest in it, better not to reply with your absurd comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wait(2000 ) releases the lock on B, and puts the thread A into a wait state. 
 it means that it has to wait for another  thread 'b' to complete its execution atleast for 2 seconds otherwise it will go to Runnable state, but not running