# JavaFX. Adding items to the list in different threads is not working

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, collections

I have 2 class.
First class is *controller*. When you click on the **enter** button, in the collection adding many objects in different threads and presented this collection as the class of the controller when the loop exits after 10 iterations.

```
public class Controller {
    private int count = 3;

    @FXML
    private Button enter;

    @FXML
    public void getData() throws IOException{
        //Create collection
        List<String> synchList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

            Runnable myThread= new MyThread(synchList); 
            executor.execute(myThread);

        }

        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println(synchList); //Show collection
}
```

The second class is *MyThread*. It performs some task. The received object is stored in collection early (for example, add 3 of the object with a delay, simulating the performance of some task)

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{
    public List<String> list = null; 

    public MyThread(List<String> list){
        this.list = list;   
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            list.add("Object2");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            list.add("Object3");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the code execution, I get **an empty list**. Please tell me what am I doing wrong and how to fix this situation? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Java thread wait for another thread's output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289434/how-to-make-a-java-thread-wait-for-another-threads-output)

Comment: It's not duplicate, because this does not apply to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation of `ExecutorService.shutdown`:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--)

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>
> **This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.**

Using `shutdown` only prevents new tasks from being submitted. It does not make sure all tasks are finished.

Instead you could use `awaitTermination` to achieve the desired effect:

```
executor.shutdown();

while (true) {
    try {
        if (executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)) {
            break;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}

System.out.println(synchList); //Show collection
```

You should however make sure the code isn't run from the application thread, since otherwise the GUI becomes unresponsive...

**Update**

In case you want the results to be added sequentially, implementing `Callback<List<String>>` with `MyThread` and using the results would be the better option, since this allows you to retrieve results from the tasks (sublists of the final list) and combine the results to a single list:

```
public class MyThread implements Callable<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> call() throws Exception {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList(2);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        list.add("Object2");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        list.add("Object3");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return list;
    }
}
```

```
//Create collection
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);

Callable<List<String>>[] tasks = new Callable[10];
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    tasks[i] = new MyThread();
}

List<Future<List<String>>> futures = executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(tasks));
executor.shutdown();

for (Future<List<String>> future : futures) {
    // combine results
    resultList.addAll(future.get());
}

System.out.println(resultList); //Show collection
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! It's work! But, what can i use if I want objects in the collection were added sequentially?

Comment: @Tomas In this case it is indeed better to use `Future` (but also `Callable<List<String>>`), since this is exactly what `Future` is supposed to be used for. See my edit.

Comment: thanks. It's good answer! @hoaz wrote about `Future` in her example too,

Answer (score 1):

You do not wait for task completion and shutdown executor before tasks even start.
Try following:

```
List<Future<?>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Runnable myThread = new MyThread(synchList); 
    results.add(executor.submit(myThread));
}

// wait loop
for (Future<?> result : results) {
    result.get();
}

executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks! But, you mean that I need to add another to the collection List<Future<?>> results ? p.s. results.add() don't work.

Comment: Yes, results.add should work fine with this method: `Future<?> submit(Runnable task)`