# AtomicBoolean for thread-safe Closeable

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

To guarantee idempotent close() operation in a `Closeable` class that could potentially be closed from multiple threads, I thought of using `AtomicBoolean`:

```
private AtomicBoolean closing = new AtomicBoolean(false);

@Override
public void close() {
    if (!closing.getAndSet(true)) {
        ...do some non-idempotent operations...
    }
}
```

Is this a correct way of doing it? I saw some uses of `compareAndSet` while searching. Which method should I use for this purpose - `getAndSet` or `compareAndSet` - and why?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. How about all the other methods? How are they made thread-safe? E.g. how do you prevent closing the object while it is in the middle of executing another method in different thread? Thread-safety applies to all the methods, and whatever mechanism you use applies to them all.

Comment: You could perhaps build something using a CountDownLatch, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42047944/how-to-make-sure-that-method-is-executed-only-once-and-from-one-thread-only All other methods will then probably have to check your `closing`-boolean and fail (exception?) if it is true.

Comment: In this case you can use either. See the linked question. In my personal opinion, using `compareAndSet(false, true)` makes your intent clearer.